How to determine dihedral angle?
How to determine dihedral angle for a high
wing ga aircraft with 12' wing span?
While there are formulas for determining
size of the vertical and
horizontal tails, I have yet to find a simple
formula for determining the dihedral angle.
According to the aircraft design book
"Flying on your own Wings" by Chris Heinz,
the designwr of such aircraft as the
CH701 STOL aircraft, the author suggests
using 3 degrees for low wing, and 6 degrees
for low wing, but I would assume this is
just valid for traditional ga wingspans
of 25' to 30' and not short wings spans such as 12',

Did you mean to write "using 3 degrees for low wing, and 6 degrees for low wing", or something else?

I bet "using 3 degrees for high wing, and 6 degrees for low wing" was intended.

Are you designing a (possibly hypothetical) plane, or trying to measure ("determine"?) the dihedral angle of an exisiting plane?

You have to decide how much counter roll response due to sideslip (roll/yaw couple) you want. You get positive dihedral effect with a high wing with zero geometric dihedral, just milder than if you add geometric dihedral. Lots of high wing airplanes have straight across wings. The Wittman Tailwind has a short span, only about 20ft +/-, with zero geometric dihedral, and its roll stability is adequate, being intended as a fast cross country airplane, tho some builders will add a degree or two of geometric dihedral to enhance it.

“High-wing airplanes often have little or no dihedral [or even anhedral], whereas many low-wing airplanes have geometric dihedral angles of as much as 10 deg.”  Airplane Flight Dynamics and Automatic Flight Controls, by Jan Roskam.
First, I'm assuming your design requirements for maintainability, visibility, manufacturability, propulsion system integration, or landing gear integration do not factor into your choice of dihedral. Therefore, this answer will focus on the primary aerodynamic stability & control effect of dihedral, which is its effect on roll due to the sideslip angle, Beta (ClB).
It's important to recognize some other key geometric parameters (in addition to the wing position relative to the fuselage) that effect ClB, especially wing sweep, wing aspect ratio, and details of the vertical tail geometry.
You want the entire configuration’s ClB to be < 0 for static stability. However, if it’s too negative (i.e., too laterally stable), the Dutch roll mode is aggravated. Also, it could result in slow rates for commanded rolls.
All things being equal, more wing dihedral tends to decrease ClB, therefore adding lateral stability.
For conceptual design on a traditional configuration, I would simply choose zero dihedral from a purely aero/S&C perspective. Beyond conceptual design, some low-order computational aerodynamics tools could provide a decent check that you’re in the ballpark*. If/when getting more serious in terms of tooling, capital and/or life & limb at stake, wind tunnel test and 6-DoF simulation will substantially burn down risks.
Fundamentals of Aircraft and Airship Design, by Nicolai & Carichner is another good reference
*Shoot for ballpark -0.1/rad for derivative of rolling moment coefficient wrt sideslip angle

Dihedral angle is measured as a positive (or negative) angle to a horizontal plane running perpendicular to the aircraft vertical centerline, viewed head on.
Since you are working with a 12" model, there is plenty of room for experimentation!  Glide you model in a cross-wind, and see what it does.
The old high wing/low wing saws for full scale aircraft do apply to models but it is important to know where your vertical Center of Gravity is.
If your model turns into the cross-wind, the dihedral effect (to a cross-wind) is not too strong, if it turns away and tries to fly downwind, the there is too much dihedral.
Dihedral effect can be reduced by raising the center of gravity, reducing dihedral, reducing sweep, or by adding side area below the vertical CG.
Fancy spats on fixed landing gear would work well to do this (and possibly also reduce drag).  Lowering the vertical stabilizer a bit would also help.

I think the O.P. is in fact asking about a 12 foot wingspan, not a 12 inch wingspan. That may affect the "room for experimentation" available.

I believe the concern is: do the angles scale.  They do, and other factors are involved in good crosswind performance.  Gliding tests remain essential, and scale models could be built.  There is also a wealth of knowledge going back many years for mono and biplane designs.
